# Installing jdk without sudo?

Tags: linux, eclipse, java

Currently, I have a machine on which I am working in Eclipse, it says that the JRE System Library version is sun-jdk-1.5.0.11 but on my active development machine, it is java-6-sun-1.6.0.16. Is there any way I can make the first machine to use the same "java-6-sun-1.6.0.16" version  without having sudo permissions on the machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install the JDK in a non-standard directory, for example under your own home directory, without special permissions.

You just need to point PATH and JAVA_HOME and Eclipse at it.

Answer (score 5):

The great thing with Java on Linux (and quite some other Unices) is that you don't need the "root" password to install it.  I do this all the time.  This is in sharp contrast with Windows where, last time I checked, it was impossible to install Java without having an admin password.

All you need is a repertory in which you put the JRE (or JDK) and then put it on the path:

```
... $ export PATH=~/jdk1.6.0_17/bin:$PATH

... $ which java
/home/wizard/jdk1.6.0_17/bin/java

... $ java -version
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 14.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

In the same vein, you can keep several JVM in the same user account and simply change the path as needed (or point your IDE to the correct JVM: for example I'm running IntelliJ IDEA with an 1.6 VM but compiling and runnning all my unit tests using a 1.5 VM).