# Incompatible JVM message when trying to install eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jvm

I just completed a Selenium Webdriver course using a borrowed windows laptop. However as I use Macs at home I am trying to install Eclipse on my own iMac using OSX 10.11.4.

I downloaded and ran the installer for Eclipse but I got the error message "Incompatible JVM - version 1.7.0_79 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version 1.8or greater is required"

So I installed the latest version of java (1.8) which went fine, however when I try to launch Eclipse again I get the same message. And when I enter Java -version into the terminal I still java version "1.7.0_79"

I did a bit of digging around and I came across a thread from a couple of years back [Java 1.7 on OSX 10.9.2 running as 1.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700845/java-1-7-on-osx-10-9-2-running-as-1-5) which appears to state that the solution to this is

rm -rf ~/Library/Java/Extensions
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/Extensions

Now I am not a very technical person and when I entered these commands into the terminal window I got the message :

ARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

So I aborted until I can find out if this is still the solution as this was the solution 3 years ago and is this all I need to do to get this issue fixed.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: You have to uninstall the old JDK.

Comment: You must install the full JDK, not just the JRE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing jdk without sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549873/installing-jdk-without-sudo)